# authenticating a twitter user id using twitter api

Tags: python-3.x, api, twitter, bots

i am able to fetch all the data based on my developer account's keys from tweepy api. But i am not sure how to dynamically authenticate a new user id with the help of twitter api and fetch information of that.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ! While asking question on forum, help people with scenario which you are trying, if possible sudo code snippet and issue you are facing while doing it. Way to go!

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. I’m making a twitter bot which will detect whether the entered user account is a bot account or not. I am unable to find a twitter api which will send me the response of validation  of the entered user I’d from twitter.